# Is this a weed?

Tags: identification

Not much to say, I have no idea what this is. Looks cool but wild like a weed.[image][image]

Comment: Somehow I missed the "a" in the title and was horribly confused for a minute xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its one of the Pokeweeds, most  likely Phytolacca americana, native to parts of the United States. Seeds itself freely, but is actually toxic, though its fine so long as you don't eat it, but probably not a good plant to keep if you have children. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana

Comment: Note that it reseeds like a fiend - usually in someone else's yard, thanks to birds. I had it it my spinach this year, which meant much careful sorting of leaves before eating. Yes, pokeweed can kill you if eaten

Comment: Oh wow. Wasn’t expecting that. Thank you very much for enlightening me. I cut it down - the stalk was pretty thick.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a weed. It does have several uses. It is what we call poke around my area of Kentucky. Also known as phytolacca americana, it sprouts up all across North America. The other answer mentions it being poisonous, though true, it was still a common dish in my childhood home. Poke sallet is a dish made from the plant’s slightly-less-toxic leaves. The leaves were boiled in water three times to cook out their toxins. It's a regional thing, popular mostly in Appalachia and the American South. It was also made into a tonic and used as a vermifuge, a worm purger. The berries of this plant can be used to make a natural rich deep magenta dye.

Comment: Yes, it's eaten in the South, but if you don't cook it correctly you will poison yourself. This is from Drugs.com's Pokeweed page: "Ingestion of poisonous parts of the plant may cause severe stomach cramping, nausea with persistent diarrhea and vomiting, slow and difficult breathing, weakness, spasms, hypotension, severe convulsions, and death."